# Ionic imagePicker is not opening gallery

Tags: javascript, image, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the following Ionic plugin so that I can open the gallery and choose multiple images: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker#installation

The **problem** that I'm facing is that when I tap the button to see "My Photos" I just get nothing come up.

In order to install I started by running the following, which is part of the **installation** of the plugin in docs:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker
npm install @ionic-native/image-picker
```

At this point, I have the following code to run the image picker:

**HTML**

```
<button ion-button full round (tap)="openImagePicker()">My Photos</button>
```

**TS**

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker/ngx';
```

...

```
  constructor(
    ...
    private camera: Camera, 
    private imagePicker: ImagePicker,
  ) {
```

...

```
  openImagePicker(){
    let options= {
      maximumImagesCount: 5,
    }
    var photos = [];
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results);
    }, (err) => { console.log(err) });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. As your app is Ionic V3 you should use below commands to install the plugin and node module.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker --variable PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"

npm install --save @ionic-native/image-picker@4
```

[Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/image-picker/)